# refering a button to a specific li?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a html tag in my react app like this

```
<ul>
   <li>
      Item 1
      <button>
         Delete
      </button>
   </li>
   <li>
      Item 2
      <button>
         Delete
      </button>
   </li> 
   <li>
      Item 3
      <button>
         Delete
      </button>
   </li>   
</ul>
```

Now, if I click Delete button from one of my li elements, I want to delete that specific li. How do I refer the button clicked to that specific li using javascript only?

Comment: Use a map that'll solve all your problem

Comment: @GermaVinsmoke can you explain more? I've seen some other solution, but it's always involving some jquery, is there any other way using javascript only or 'reactjs' way?

Comment: Give an id to all the li tags using map then on button click you can use that id and delete it

Comment: @GermaVinsmoke I see your point now, you can put that in the answer, and I will mark that as accepted answer.

Comment: I'm trying that man, this internet not working properly XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to generate your items and attach an `onClick` handler like this:

```js
class Demo extends React.Component {
  state = { items: ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3'] };
  
  handleDelete = name => {
    this.setState(s => ({ items: s.items.filter(x => x !== name) }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>{this.state.items.map(x =>
        <li>{x}&nbsp;
          <button onClick={() => this.handleDelete(x)}>Delete</button>
        </li>
      )}</ul>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Demo />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

If you do not want to generate a delete function for each item and handle the deletion in a single function, you will have to add an id of some kind to your items to identify them. Then you can attach this id to the button using a data attribute and get this id from the `event.target` in the handler:

```js
class Demo extends React.Component {
  state = {
    items: [
      { id: 1, content: 'Item 1' },
      { id: 2, content: 'Item 2' },
      { id: 3, content: 'Item 3' }
    ]
  };
  
  handleDelete = e => {
    const id = +e.target.getAttribute('data-id');
    this.setState(s => ({ items: s.items.filter(x => x.id !== id) }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>{this.state.items.map(({ id, content }) =>
        <li key={id}>{content}&nbsp;
          <button data-id={id} onClick={this.handleDelete}>Delete</button>
        </li>
      )}</ul>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Demo />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: is there any other way than this that more efficient? I heard that putting an arrow function inside each element of array like that is costly, because you generate a function for each element instead of generate one function that can handle each element.

Comment: @Kevin Chandra, I would suggest to not worry about this until you do have performance problems, passing functions around is something that is done everywhere in functional languages.

Comment: Sure, but I still want to know if there any other solution

Comment: @Kevin Chandra, I will update my answer and add a snippet for another way to do it

Comment: thanks for the other solution, however that is the same solution from GermaVinsmoke. Actually I heard the other solution is to wrap the button with some other component which has a prop of the element's id or content and also a prop of the function to handle it which is handleDelete in this case. But still, I only grasp the concept of it.

Comment: @Kevin Chandra, wrapping the button in another component will be less efficient than the first solution though, which was to give each button its unique function with the id already baked in. Wrapping a component implies a new function or class and possibly a DOM node too

Answer (score 0):

You can give id properties to your button element based on id from li element, and use that id when referring the item that want to be deleted.