# Other way to creating a function that can receive param from each element from array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's say I have a function renderList and handleClick, which is

```
handleClick = name => {
   alert(name);
}


renderList(){
   var list = [{name:'name1',age:1},{name:'name2',age:2},{name:'name3',age:3}]

   return(
      <ul>
      {list.map(x =>
         <li>
            {x.name + " ---> " + x.age}
            <div onClick = {()=>{this.handleClick(x.name)}}>
               Click Me
            </div>
         </li>
      )}
      </ul>
   );

}
```

When I click the "Click Me" div, it will alert the name of the element clicked, but using arrow function for onClick in that div is implying that each element has it own function, and I don't want that.

Other solution is:

```
handleClick = event => {
       alert(event.target.id);
    }


renderList(){
   var list = [{name:'name1',age:1},{name:'name2',age:2},{name:'name3',age:3}]

   return(
      <ul>
      {list.map(x =>
         <li>
            {x.name + " ---> " + x.age}
            <div id = {x.name} onClick = {this.handleClick}>
               Click Me
            </div>
         </li>
      )}
      </ul>
   );

}
```

this way, by giving an id to my div, I can achieve the same result with the first code. But let's say there is another case when I need to pass other parameter that I can't give to the div's id.

So the question is, is there any other way that can achieve the same result without using the 2 ways mentioned above?

(This question is related with my other question in [refering a button to a specific li?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55075591/refering-a-button-to-a-specific-li))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use a unique id for each item so you can find the related entry in the array**.
Using this technique, you only attach the id to the DOM and then use it to get your data from your state.
In your case, let's pretend `name` is unique:

```js
class Demo extends React.Component {
  state = {
    items: [{ name: 'name1', age: 1 }, { name: 'name2', age: 2 }, { name: 'name3', age: 3 }]
  };
  
  handleClick = event => {
    const item = this.state.items.find(x => x.name === event.target.id);
    console.log(item);
  };
  
  render() {
    return (
      <ul>{this.state.items.map(({ name, age }) =>
         <li key={name}>
            name: {name} age: {age}&nbsp;
            <button id={name} onClick={this.handleClick}>
               Click Me
            </button>
         </li>
      )}</ul>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Demo />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

**If you want to be more efficient, use an object to associate your items to their `id`**. Then use `Object.values()` to get your array of items:

```js
class Demo extends React.Component {
  state = {
    items: {
      name1: { name: 'name1', age: 1 },
      name2: { name: 'name2', age: 2 },
      name3: { name: 'name3', age: 3 }
    }
  };
  
  handleClick = event => {
    console.log(this.state.items[event.target.id]);
  };
  
  render() {
    return (
      <ul>{Object.values(this.state.items).map(({ name, age }) =>
         <li key={name}>
            name: {name} age: {age}&nbsp;
            <button id={name} onClick={this.handleClick}>
               Click Me
            </button>
         </li>
      )}</ul>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Demo />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

**Another way is to pass your data by attaching it as data attributes on your element**. Then you can get those attributes with `event.target.getAttribute('data-age')` for example.

```js
class Demo extends React.Component {
  state = {
    items: [{ name: 'name1', age: 1 }, { name: 'name2', age: 2 }, { name: 'name3', age: 3 }]
  };
  
  handleClick = event => {
    const age = event.target.getAttribute('data-age');
    console.log(event.target.id, age);
  };
  
  render() {
    return (
      <ul>{this.state.items.map(({ name, age }) =>
         <li key={name}>
            name: {name} age: {age}&nbsp;
            <button id={name} data-age={age} onClick={this.handleClick}>
               Click Me
            </button>
         </li>
      )}</ul>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Demo />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: if you have any other way in mind, please let me know. Thanks

Comment: @Kevin Chandra, I have nothing else in mind for now!

Comment: @Kevin Chandra, just a warning, I prefer to use `data-id` instead of `id` to avoid id conflicts since an id must be unique for the whole page and so across different lists

Answer (score 2):

Another option, without putting anything unnecessary into the DOM, is to check the clicked element's `li`'s index in the parent `ul` on click:

```js
class List extends React.Component {
  list = [{name:'name1',age:1},{name:'name2',age:2},{name:'name3',age:3}]
  handleClick = ({ target }) => {
    const li = target.parentElement;
    const index = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(li.parentElement.children, li);
    console.log(this.list[index].name);
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <ul>
      {this.list.map(x =>
         <li>
            {x.name + " ---> " + x.age}
            <div onClick = {this.handleClick}>
               Click Me
            </div>
         </li>
      )}
      </ul>
   );
  }
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <List />,
  container
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```